# how to get selected value from a dropdown on click in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby on rails please help me with this simple code :
I need to print 
'HI' if option 1 is selected
'BONJOUR' if option 2,
'HOLA' if option 3,
'NAMASTE' if option 4.

on selecting a value on the dropdown and click the button,

```
<%= form_for :person do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :desired_attribute, ['option1','option2','option3','option4']%>
  <%= button_to "Show Text" , :onclick => "show_back(), return false" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need  to add on change https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp event

and get the selected value from the dropdown using it's id

Comment: Is any method to do the same with the controller ? I mean without js?? just asking

Answer (score 1):

involve your server.

view. Add `remote: true` to your form. And handle ajax request in controller. [more about ajax in rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

```
<%= form_for :person, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :desired_attribute, options_for_select([ ['option1', '1'],['option2', '2'],['option3', '3'],['option4', '4']]) %>
  <%= button_to "Show Text" , :onclick => "show_back(), return false" %>
<% end %>
```

in your controller

```
class PersonsController
  MY_HASH = { '1': 'HI', '2': 'BONJOUR', '3': 'HOLA', '4': 'NAMASTE' }

  def name_of_action
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'your_partial_name', name: MY_HASH[params[:person][:desired_attribute]] }
  end
end
```

your_partial_name.js.erb

```
alert("<%= name %>");
```

Instead of `MY_HASH` it's better to use `I18n` to handle language issues. [more about I18n](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
<%= f.select :point1, options_for_select([ ['option1', 'HI'],['option2', 'BONJOUR'],['option3', 'HOLA'],['option4', 'NAMASTE']]) %>
```

you will dropdown like this:

```
<select id="point1">
  <option value="HI">option1</option>
  <option value="BONJOUR">option2</option>
  <option value="HOLA">option3</option>
  <option value="NAMASTE">option4</option>
</select>
```

Dropdown option map with its value then you will get the value.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to render the HI/BONJOUR/HOLA/NAMASTE in HTML, in some tags(h1,h2 etc)